# Transmitir con multiples camaras con OpenCV y Flask reconociendo la ID via la URL

Tags: python, flask, opencv

Este enlace muestra como hacer que una camara se transmita con opencv via Flask: https://manivannan-ai.medium.com/live-webcam-flask-opencv-python-26a61fee831

Aqui el codigo:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)
video = cv2.VideoCapture(id) #RECIBE LA ID

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Default Message"
def gen(video):
    while True:
        success, image = video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        frame = jpeg.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    global video
    return Response(gen(video),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=2204, threaded=True)
```

Como dice el titulo, lo que quiero es transmitir varias camaras. Cada camara la identifico con una ID. Me gustaria poder dar el ID desde @app.route('')

Ejemplo
@app.route('/id')

... ya que pasare la ID desde el enlace, y lo recibe **video = cv2.VideoCapture(id)**

Comment: en la ruta debes indicar que quieres recibir un parámetro, así `@app.route('/<int:id>')`

Comment: Como hago para que reciba la ID el codigo? Recuerda que el def index(): llama al html y def gen(video) es el que tiene el codigo, porque estoy intentando eso que dices y no lo logro.

Comment: got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Comment: Bueno creo que mejor hago una respuesta, espera un momento

Comment: MIl gracias por la ayuda, Christian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay que aclarar una cosa, al poner el decorador `@app.route("/")`indicas que el parámetro de `route("/")` va a ser la ruta, en este caso la ruta inicial `/`. Por lo que veo quieres que la ruta `/video_feed` sea la reciba el `id` para poder conectar la cámara. por lo que deberíamos indicarle otro parámetro dinámico que será el `id`. Asi:

```py
@app.route('/video_feed/<int:id>')
def video_feed(id):#le indicamos que recibira un parametro
    global video
    video = id
    return Response(gen(video),#le podemos pasar video o id
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Comment: Recuerda que **video = cv2.VideoCapture(id) #RECIBE LA ID** esta afuera. y tu escribiste que video = id, ID es el index del VideoCapture, no el valor completo de VideoCapture

Comment: Deberias poner el código completo, si tienes `cv2.VideoCapture()` afuera, deberás ponerlo en uns función

Comment: Funciono perfectamente. No se si puedo hacerte una pregunta aqui mismo, pero, la hare... por que es muy lento? No parece un video, quizas porque la camara es 2k?

Comment: Bueno mientras no transmitas utilizando una red de internet esto no tendrá nada que ver, openCv hace una conexión *nativa* la cual puedes visualizar en una ventana (en este caso lo haces por una web), lo mas probable es que si sea por la cámara, no soy experto así que me puedo equivocar

Comment: Uso una camara IP y todo lo voy a tener en un servidor de AWS, ahora mismo lo corro en local y esta lento, crees que en el servidor estara rapido?

Comment: Otra pregunta con relacion a lo que dijiste, a que te refieres a que opencv es nativo? Solo va a correr en una ventana y no globalmente?

Comment: como dije si no haces una transmisión (osea que no vas a mandar el video en vivo a otra pc) no habrá problemas, de lo contrario podría haber problemas de conexión. Además puede depender de la cámara del usuario

Comment: en cuando a lo de opencv dije que hace una *conexion nativa* osea el mismo opencv se encarga de abrir tu cámara y mostrarte el video